# Processes started without a network connection are permanently unable to use it

Tags: linux, networkmanager, manjaro

In a nutshell: The first time a process tries to use a connection, if it fails due to no connections available, that single process will never regain the ability to use the network. I have to kill and restart it.

I have a ruby script that tries to resolve 'google.com' three times. If I disable networking (through NetworkManager) or hit my physical WLAN switch off, start the script, let it fail once, then re-enable networking, the other two resolves will also fail, even though the rest of the system has networking.

A similar Python script exhibits the same results, as well as the browser lynx. Not Firefox though! These behaviors are all tested on both a VM and a physical machine running the latest Manjaro x64 XFCE. On the latest Ubuntu x64, the same tests work fine.

Why does this happen? Is this a bug, feature, quirk?

**EDIT:**

On Manjaro, the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are regenerated by resolvconf.

- Network enabled: `search lan; nameserver 192.168.1.1`
- Network disabled: empty file

Ruby/Python/Lynx must only read `resolv.conf` once. So, on first request, it finds the empty file, and is never again able to resolve any names.

And on Ubuntu, `/etc/resolv.conf`:

- Network enabled: `nameserver 127.0.1.1; search lan`
- Network disabled: `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

So when Ruby/Python/Lynx read it on disabled network, they'll still have a nameserver to contact when a connection comes back up. The problem with Manjaro's setup is that with no connection, there are no nameservers. Ubuntu runs dnsmasq for 127.0.1.1 and Manjaro does not.

Comment: Guess: The Python or Ruby interpreter read `resolv.conf` once, and then never again, so they are not aware of changes. Google for "linux resolver" for an explanation how name resolving works.

Comment: I would suggest setting `resolv.conf` the way you want it and making it immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, there are two solutions.

1. Edit resolvconf.conf: `name_servers=192.168.1.1` or whatever your most common nameservers are. Problem: not every nameserver is `192.168.1.1` like mine. If you connect with a different network, your process will stay broken since a nameserver at `192.168.1.1` might not exist there.
2. [Let NetworkManager setup and use dnsmasq](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#NetworkManager) by adding a few lines to `NetworkManager.conf`

I tried both, and the symptom was averted with either. The second one seems more clean, and is easier to set up, but is not as lightweight.